# How to return what's being entered in input - JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia

I am working on a search feature for my site using Algolia. The user enters their search term, and as they type the results are updated with the relevant result matches.

I have an example below of what I am trying to accomplish:

https://codesandbox.io/s/algolia-search-yy126?file=/src/App.js

Basically, I am trying to figure out how to make the red text show what has been entered in the searchbox and update as the user types. so that it can say something like "results for ..."

Does anyone have any input on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your input has a value and onChange property. assign the value to a state and update that state in the onChange function.

```
this.state = { userInput: "" }

<input type="text value={this.state.userInput} onChange=(e => this.setState({userInput: e.target.value})/>
```

with this you will always have the userInput value and u can fetch immediately.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with hooks, do you have an example for that? I'm not that great with understanding hooks yet, i am trying to learn

Comment: yes, first import {useState} from "react" then const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("") and ur input tag will be like this: <input type="text value={userInput} onChange=(e => setUserInput(e).target.value )/>

Comment: awesome :) i just noticed i have a typo here i correct it : <input type="text" value={userInput} onChange=(e => setUserInput(e.target.value ))/>